# Webpack and dust-core.js incompatible

Tags: webpack, dust.js

I'm working on a [webpack loader for dust.js](https://github.com/wombatsecurity/dust-loader-complete). It works pretty well as long as I require the entire dustjs npm module via `require('dustjs-linkedin)`. However, I want to require just the core (`dist/dust-core`) because the loader itself compiles the templates.

The issue appears to be that webpack is seeing the following:

```
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd && define.amd.dust === true) {
  define(["require", "dust.core"], function(require, dust) {
    dust.onLoad = function(name, cb) {
        require([name], function() {
            cb();
        });
    };
    return dust;
  });
}
```

and automatically turning on [code-splitting](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html). Specifically, the `require([name], ...)` call is causing webpack to attempt to package all of the files inside the `dist` folder. I can use a plugin to turn code-splitting off entirely, but then that makes my loader much less useful.

Is anybody using webpack to require dust.js and running into a similar issue? Has anybody solved that issue? I'm thinking of trying to contribute a fix that generates a webpack-friendly version of `dust-core.js`.

Comment: Could you just use `lib/dust` directly? The code block you reference above is the only difference between `dist/dust-core` and `lib/dust` (it's added during the build process)

Comment: Thank you, @Interrobang. I hesitated to add a dependency directly from the lib directory, because I didn't know what the build process would do. But it appears to work great. If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to directly use `lib/dust` in your build.

When Dust is built into `dist`, AMD loader support for `dust.onLoad` is added as part of the build process, but you won't need that piece of code, and it's the code that's giving you trouble above.